# while loop variable inclusion

Tags: bash, while-loop, increment

I have the following while loop:

```
while read LINE; do
  VALUE="`echo $LINE | cut -d"|" -f1`";
done
```

Notice the f1. This is the normal way I would use cut. This time around though, I need to increment f1 kinda like this:

```
while read LINE; do
  VALUE="`echo $LINE | cut -d"|" -f$COUNT`";
done
```

I cannot figure out the correct syntax. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

*** UPDATE ***

Here is my complete code (if this helps more)

```
declare -a FIELDS
local i
for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
  local COUNT=1
  while read LINE; do
    VALUE="`echo $LINE | cut -d"|" -f$COUNT`";
    FIELDS[$COUNT]="$VALUE"

      Do stuff to each element of array here

    let COUNT=COUNT+1
  done < <(grep -v '#' databases/${DBARRAY[$i]})
done
```

*** UPDATE ***

Ok so I just realized my logic was flawed. The first for loop is to loop through all the databases. The while loop is to loop through every line in a single database. I needed a third loop to store each field to the array. See updated code below:

```
declare -a FIELDS
local i
local j
for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
  local COUNT=1
  while read LINE; do
    for (( j=1; j<=24; j++ )); do
      VALUE="`echo $LINE | cut -d"|" -f"$j"`";
      FIELDS[$j]="$VALUE"
      echo "${FIELDS[$j]}"
    done
    let COUNT=COUNT+1
  done < <(grep -v '#' databases/${DBARRAY[$i]})
done
```

This code works woot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `read` command itself to split the line:

```
for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
    while IFS='|' read -ra FIELDS; do
        printf "%s\n" "${FIELDS[@]}"
    done < <(grep -v '#' databases/${DBARRAY[$i]})
done
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just realized my logic was flawed. The first for loop is to loop through all the databases. The while loop is to loop through every line in a single database. I needed a third loop to store each field to the array. See updated code below:

```
declare -a FIELDS
local i
local j
for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
  local COUNT=1
  while read LINE; do
    for (( j=1; j<=24; j++ )); do
      VALUE="`echo $LINE | cut -d"|" -f"$j"`";
      FIELDS[$j]="$VALUE"
      echo "${FIELDS[$j]}"
    done
    let COUNT=COUNT+1
  done < <(grep -v '#' databases/${DBARRAY[$i]})
done
```

This code works woot!